# Error in deploying WSO2 .car file in a remote server

Tags: deployment, wso2, truststore, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to deploy car file using maven in to a remote server. I have generated the truststore JKS as per the instructions in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Creating+New+Keystores.

But when I try to deploy the CAR file with maven it's giving me the following error:

**[ERROR] Uploading XXXAPICompositeApplication_1.0.0.car to https://ei.domain.com Failed.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) http://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin**

I have tested this in my local and there is no issue.

I am wondering why it refers to a local EPR even though I have given a remote server. Please advice me to resolve this.

Detailed error log is as follows:

```
--- maven-car-deploy-plugin:1.1.1:deploy-car (default-deploy-car) @ XXXAPICompositeApplication ---
[INFO] Deploying to Server...
[INFO] TSPath=/home/sampath/Desktop/EI-cert/domain.com.jks
[INFO] TSPWD=xxxxx
[INFO] TSType=JKS
[INFO] Server URL=https://ei.domain.com
[INFO] UserName=admin
[INFO] Password=xxxxxxxxxxxx
[INFO] Operation=deploy
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[ERROR] Uploading XXXAPICompositeApplication_1.0.0.car to https://ei.domain.com Failed.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) http://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.wso2.carbon.stub.AuthenticationAdminStub.login(AuthenticationAdminStub.java:659)
```

Comment: I am using WSO2 EI 6.4 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be as simple as a mismatch between port and protocol?  Typically, HTTP and 9443 don't go together.  Perhaps try HTTPS?

Comment: OK, the reason I bring that up is that the endpoint reported in your stack above is  http://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin  which is http and 9443.